# Site title displays differently for different pages on same site

Tags: html, css, fonts

Weird problem.

My site's title displays differently on two different pages of my site, but the computed CSS is the same when I inspect the element.

Site: [ryantuck.io](http://ryantuck.io)

How it looks across the site:

[image]

And how it looks on the about-site page [here](http://ryantuck.io/about-site/):

[image]

Why would this happen, and how could I fix it?

Comment: looks exactly the same for me, at least on Firefox. Also, it has exactly the same properties in inspector

Comment: the two versions also had the same properties for me in inspector, which is why i was confused. Was rectified by the accepted answer. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What browser are you using? The title displays just fine here in Safari & Chrome. Try to empty your cache maybe?

It looks to have something to do with `-webkit-font-smoothing` or something like that, maybe try to add `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` after all your stylesheets.

Comment: I added `*{-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;}` to the end of my css file and it fixed the problem on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, Times New Roman on one page, sans serif on another. I added:

```
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
```

to the CSS and it fixed the problem. Also, check if this helps:

```
font-style:normal;
font-weight: 400;
```